# Java for return phone keypads

Tags: java, keypad

I get a problem about returning phone keypads.
For instance, if I input 1-80-0Apple, it will return 1-80-027753.
Could somebody tell me how to figure out this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to deal with different formats for phone numbers entered by users I would suggest that you use Google's libphonenumber (http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/). It has lots of utilities for handling phone numbers.

For the case that you ask, you can do this:

```
String phoneNumber = PhoneNumberUtil.convertAlphaCharactersInNumber("1-80-0Apple");
System.out.println(phoneNumber);
```

That would print:

```
1-80-027753
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a lookup table between letters and numbers:

```
A -> 2
B -> 2
C -> 2
D -> 3
etc
```

Then loop through each letter in the number and replace it with the corresponding number.